# Showing a list of events

Tags: user-interface

Our site, http://www.racedayworld.com has events that you can register for which are listed in an accordion control by each month ..

I've been getting feedback that says people aren't looking past the first open month as they are not too familiar with the whole accordion thing ..

Can anyone post any suggestions on what type of control I could use that would work - I wanted to do something which wasn't just a normal boring table, but I haven't been really able to think of anything as of yet .. let me know if you have any suggestions..

Answer (score 0):

How about a tree view, or something like the MacOS Finder? On the left a scrolling pane with each month, saying "January: 12 Events" or similar on each line. Then clicking that updates the right pane to a scrollable list of the events...

Done with unobtrusive javascript of course so it degrades nicely. No clues in your tags if you're doing this in Flash...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider keeping the control and just do something to draw attention to it. For example, add a "swoopy" arrow that points to the second month with the words "click here for more events!". Just make sure you can disable that once someone expands that second month.